# why can not my php script export complete csv file in my site?

Tags: php, csv

I export the csv file from my site using php , can only get about 8k codes.
but when I using the same php script to export csv from my local test site , I can get completely codes ,about 500k. I am sure that the datebase in the site is the same with my local pc test datebase.

[image]

```
function export(){
        ini_set ('memory_limit', '32M');
        $this->db->execute('set names utf8');
        $result=$this->db->execute($this->query_sql);
        $csv_code='';
        $keys_line='';
        if($result->recordCount()>0){
            while(!$result->EOF){
                $v=$result->fields;


                // 标题行
                if($keys_line==''){
                    foreach($v as $k1=>$v1){
                        $keys_arr[]=$k1;
                    }
                    $keys_line=implode(',',$keys_arr);
                    $csv_code.=$keys_line;
                }

                // 内容行
                $values_arr=array();
                foreach($v as $k1=>$v1){
                    $str=preg_replace("@\s+@"," ",$v1); //替换换行
                    $str=preg_replace("@\"@","\"\"",$v1); //scv中需要将单个双引号转换成2个双引号
                    $str='"'.$str.'"';  // 用双引号括起来每个值
                    $values_arr[]=$str;
                }
                $values_line=implode(',',$values_arr);
                $csv_code.="\n".$values_line;
                $result->MoveNext();
            }
        }

        $filename = $this->csv_name.".csv";//文件名
        header("Content-type:text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$filename);
        header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0');
        header('Expires:0');
        header('Pragma:public');
        $csv_code=iconv('UTF-8','GB2312//IGNORE',$csv_code);    //转码成gbk
        $csv_code=trim($csv_code);
        echo $csv_code;
        exit;

    }
```

if I remove these codes , I can get all data codes in page, why?

```
// $filename = $this->csv_name.".csv";//文件名
// header("Content-type:text/csv");
// header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$filename);
// header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0');
// header('Expires:0');
// header('Pragma:public');
// $csv_code=iconv('UTF-8','GB2312//IGNORE',$csv_code); //转码成gbk
// $csv_code=trim($csv_code);
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code. But if it is very slow, you could be hitting an [execution time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: not time limit ,it is fast

Comment: Try to add content length in header. not sure

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a memory limit... try echoing out your headers prior to walking your data and echo the data instead of accumulating it in an array. You may also have to periodically call flush.